# Styles for Watch Window in Zerobrane

Tags: zerobrane

I can not find any information to change the Overlay Mask for this Watch Window. Each Style has the same problem White Text with white active Overlay for activ Watch selection O.o

macOS 10.15.5
ZeroBrane Studio (1.90; MobDebug 0.706)

[PictureSaysMoreThenWords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03O8e.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be controlled from wxwidgets (and so from the IDE), as it's set based on one of the system colors (specifically `wxSYS_COLOUR_BTNSHADOW`). You can see what the color is being returned by running the following command in the Local console in the IDE: `wx.wxSystemSettings.GetColour(wx.wxSYS_COLOUR_BTNSHADOW):GetAsString()`. Only item background and foreground colors can be set, but not the highlight (when editing) and unfocused highlight (when selected) colors.

There *may* be a hack-ish way to do this; you can send a message to IRC or the maillist if you are interested to try (https://studio.zerobrane.com/community).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this is not Zerobrane related i accept your answer and we read us again in other channels =)

Just to be clear, this is what i have seen in my console: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.267)